# How to relocate Google Maps legal label in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to relocate the Google logo in the bottom left of the GoogleMap component in jetpack compose. I am drawing some ui elements on the map and they are obscuring Google Maps logo. Is there any proper way to relocate the logo when let's say bottom sheet goes up or some ui element permanently stays on the bottom side?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Code below seems to be working for that matter

```
@Composable    
GoogleMap(
        ...
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 100.dp),
        ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me. I hope google adds the proper way to do it.